# Search results not shown in Lightning view but shown in Classic

Tags: search, global-search

A user is unable to get any search results in Lightning view, while he's able to get that in Classic view. The user does have read/write access on the record/object that he searches & is able to open the record by navigating to the object's records. Every other user in the same role & profile is able to search & fetch results in Lightning. Not sure what's causing this.

Please let me know, if anyone faced this kind of issue!

Answer (score 0):

In Lightning Experience UI: There isn’t a 'Search All' option in search results. 'Top Results' displays the most relevant records grouped by your most frequently used objects. To see results for other objects, click object names on the left side of the page, under 'Search Results.' Searchable objects are listed in the same order they appear in the navigation bar. If you don’t see an object listed under 'Search Results,' select 'Show More' to see all objects available to you, listed in alphabetical order. Refer below screenshot for your reference.
[image]

For more information, refer the help article [Link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000330207&type=1)

Comment: Thanks for the response. However user is unable to get the search results and the count next to the object on the left side is 0. They even tried to search by the exact name of the record and its still same.. also came across the link that you shared & don’t see a resolution for my issue.

Comment: If possible, can you share the screenshot of your global search?

Answer (score 0):

Setup:> Einstein Seach:> Objects to Always Search (Beta)

Select the profile of the user and choose the objects which you want a einstein search for after editing it.